# How does deadlock happen in MySQL, and how to deal with it?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb, select-for-update, exclusive-lock

I know maybe this is a frequent question, and I also have searched before asking.But I still have some points cannot figure out myself, help you can help me. Thanks in advance.

1. How does deadlock happen in MySQL? Mysql gives an example in the manual(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlock-example.html), it's seems two unrelated tables being operated, so I really don't get how deadlock occurs between two tables.
2. I saw some people say deadlock also happened in SELECT...FOR UPDATE lock, due to process order. Is true? Does the 'SELECT...FOR UPDATE' lock put the exclusive lock initially? So how did this happen?
3. If both can face deadlock situations, is there any workaround to deal with it?

Comment: Deadlocks happen when different processes try to acquire locks in different orders. The example in your link shows that. Client A locks Animals and then tries to lock  Birds; client B locks Birds and then tries to lock Animals. So when client A tries to lock Birds, he can't, because B holds it, and B is blocked trying to lock Animals, which A has locked. The solution is to always acquire the locks in the same order.

Comment: As above, the order of lock acquisition is important. If all transactions acquire locks in the same order there is no deadlocks. [WP:Deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) is a reasonable reference on the concept. MySQL provides the detection, the resolution depends on the application and its writer, you.

Comment: If Animals and Birds were two _rows_ in a single table, a similar deadlock could be demonstrated with a single table.